# In protractor , when to use protractor.promise.controlFlow() >

Tags: protractor

I'm confused when to use

```
var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow()
```

in **protractor scripts** and also I can see a method called execute method `flow.execute()`.

Can Any one give me some example and elaborate above statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't normally need to use the controlFlow yourself unless you are trying to add some asynchronous code into the middle of other webdriver operations.  You would basically have to wrap that asynchronous code inside of a promise and the pass that promise/function into the flow.execute().  Here is a good link with more information about Control Flow in WebdriverJS
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#control-flows

Comment: Can we assign any computed value to global scope in execute() method